# How do I get SVG element by using its Classname

Tags: javascript, svg

**My Sample Svg :**

```
<circle cx="205.45282275086475" cy="187.9788644175314" r="69.64553108419807" id="07539aec-9d5d-4747-8878-0da5d505cb5f" stroke="#010101" fill="none" stroke-width="2" data-pdf-annotate-id="07539aec-9d5d-4747-8878-0da5d505cb5f" data-pdf-annotate-type="emptycircle" onload="init(evt)"class="hide000000003d495a02706fb486" aria-hidden="true" transform="scale(0.6) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)" style="cursor: pointer;"></circle>
```

How I have to get the element by using its className

```
var prev_annotation = document.getElementsByClassName("hide000000003d495a02706fb486");
console.log(prev_annotation) // Am not getting the Element
```

What I have done Wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have misplaced `"`.

Please try dividing this single line in multiple lines so that you can clearly read your code.

```
<circle cx="205.45282275086475" 

cy="187.9788644175314" 

r="69.64553108419807" 

id="07539aec-9d5d-4747-8878-0da5d505cb5f"

stroke="#010101" 

fill="none" 

stroke-width="2" 

data-pdf-annotate-id="07539aec-9d5d-4747-8878-0da5d505cb5f" 

data-pdf-annotate-type="emptycircle" 

onload="init(evt)" 

class="hide000000003d495a02706fb486【**】 __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" 

aria-hidden="true" 

transform="scale(0.6) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)" 

style="cursor: pointer;"></circle>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. While your suggestion is good, you have not provided an answer.

Comment: So now you should get array of elements - more specifically an html collection- and if you have used this class only once then the array will contain only one element

Comment: @bcperth this is my answer. I pointed out the error. It is not a suggestion. Please read carefully.